# Apache Solr Datasource configuration Error

Tags: mysql, linux, solr

I have installed Apache solr with the Apache Tomcat its working fine and need to configure. 
i have added this lines to /collection1/conf/solrcongi.xml file, i just added this line only i didn't create anything for this may i want to configure any other things with this ?

```
<datasource form mysql
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"
class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">/home/username/data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Is that correct?
and configured data-source config as

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database user="dbsync" password="pass"/>
<document name="products">
<entity name="solrtest" query="select * from solrtest">
<field column="ID" name="id" />
<field column="NAME" name="name" />
<field column="MANU" name="manu" />
<field column="WEIGHT" name="weight" />
<field column="PRICE" name="price" />
<field column="POPULARITY" name="popularity" />
<field column="INSTOCK" name="inStock" />
<field column="INCLUDES" name="includes" />
<entity name="feature" query="select description from feature where       item_id='${item.ID}'">
<field name="features" column="description" />
</entity>
<entity name="item_category" query="select CATEGORY_ID from item_category where item_id='${item.ID}'">
<entity name="category" query="select description from category where id = '${item_category.CATEGORY_ID}'">
<field column="description" name="cat" />
</entity>
</entity>
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

am getting core not found error. It might be dump question,really am new one to solr. Please help to create that datasoure please give to instruction to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Solr log to see the Java stack trace. Usually the problem is obvious in the error message.

I think your problem is in this line:

```
<str name="config">/home/username/data-config.xml</str>
```

It should point to your `data-config.xml`. Remove `/home/username` part if the two files `solrconfig` and `data-config` are in the `$SOLR_HOME/conf` directory.

Comment: Yes, Am using the same architecture as per you recommended, it Couldn't help.

Comment: I figured out That is a problem with the <ID>